# Chrome CSS3 animation glitch

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, backbone.js

I'm using Chrome Version 37.0.2062.120 m

I have a carousel created in owl carousel 2 and added a number of different CSS3 animations for transitions.  The problem is Chrome always keeps a section of the top left of the carousel on screen during any transition.

It is not an element being kept on screen, but a glitch of different sizes cut through the carousel.

I have included an example here:

[image: The top image shows during the transition, the bottom one at the end of transition]

Javascript

```
    this.$el.owlCarousel({
      nav:true,
      autoplay:true,
      items:1,
      margin:5,
      loop:true,
      center:true,
      onTranslated: _.bind(this.translated,this),
      animateIn: 'fadeInDown',   // <-- css3 transition class
      animateOut: 'fadeOutDown',   // <-- css3 transition class
    });

    // gets the id of the slide and updates the data
    translated: function (){
    var currentSlideId = this.$el.find(".owl-item.active > .item").attr('id');
    slideModule.loadSlide(currentSlideId);
  }
```

css

```
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
                transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
      }

      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
                transform: none;
      }
    }

    @keyframes fadeInUp {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
                transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
      }

      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
                transform: none;
      }
    }

    .fadeInUp {
      -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
              animation-name: fadeInUp;
    }

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOutUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
}

.fadeOutUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeOutUp;
          animation-name: fadeOutUp;
}
```

Comment: maybe you could show an example in a js fiddle or inserted into your post - otherwise this information is pretty useless.

Comment: It's specific to Chrome and I believe my code is correct, I'm hoping someone came across this glitch before and knows a fix - hopefully with a magic line of css3 with a webkit vendor prefix.

Comment: hoping someone has noticed the same issue is a long shot - if you can provide example code and a live example (via the aforementioned js fiddle) then anyone with or without the problem may be able to help you.

Comment: Ok fair enough, well I'v updated the question in the hope that helps.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. I'm using jQuery to update CSS scale and position, and Chrome 37.0.2062.124 m is leaving edges of my Bootstrap panels lying around.

Comment: I see now that I was a minor version behind: http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2014/10/stable-channel-update.html In 38.0.2125.101 m I see less artifacting, though some vertical lines remain.

Comment: I'm having another chrome issue with transforms, I'v raised the issue on the Chromium bug reports and included sample code, if its anything related to this issue you can view the progress here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=539925&q=conor%40cube19.com&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
owl-carousel .owl-item { -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) !important;   }
```

hope it help :)